# Manipulating strings in python with f strings: handling long strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, formatting

How do i handle long strings while printing with f-Strings.
I am only interested in the first -and last n of the string (especially in this case the extension of a file). The middle part should be replaced with 3 dots.

As an example:

instead of:

```
ThisIsMyFilexyz123456s556s54s6afsaf1dshshsb8bbs6s7890.py

ThisIsMyFilexyz12345asaggsvrgahhgbargrarbrvs7890.pdf

ThisIsMyFilexyz12345asa46189sgvs7890.gif

ThisIsMyFilexyz1sgsgbs6rahhgbargrarbrvs7890.jpg
```

**i want this:**

```
ThisIsMyFilexy...123.py

ThisIsMyFilexy...456.pdf

ThisIsMyFilexy...789.xml

ThisIsMyFilexy...001.gif

ThisIsMyFilexy...002.py
 
ThisIsMyFilexy...003.py
```

---

```
    import os, arrow
    
    dirname = input("Enter a directory name: ")
    
    def last_modified(filename):
        statinfo = os.stat(filename)
        timestamp = statinfo.st_mtime
        utc = arrow.get(timestamp)
        local = utc.to('Europe/Berlin')
        modified_time = local.format('DD MMMM YYYY HH:mm:ss')
        return modified_time
    
    
    last_time_modified = { filename : last_modified(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
                    for filename in os.listdir(dirname)
                    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dirname, filename))}
    
# **here comes the printing part**
    for key, value in last_time_modified.items():
        print(f'{key:<35} {value:>35}')
```

Comment: Why not just print(string[:10]+"..." +string[-3:])?

Comment: it doesn't fit my f-Strings style of printing.

Comment: There is no choice but to break the string at every piece of left and right parentheses.

Comment: @blQSheep, you can't set max length using formatting

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#id27. See `Escape sequences`

Comment: Also see https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-print-a-string-at-a-fixed-width-in-python

Answer (score 1):

A combination of both, @Prem Anand & @Vishesh Mangla did it for me. Here is what i got:

```
def trunc(arg):
    if len(arg) > 35:
      return arg[:25]+"..."+arg[-10:]
    else:
        return arg

for key, value in last_time_modified.items():
    line_new = '{:<38}  {:>35}'.format(trunc(key), str(value))
    print(line_new)
```

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Define a new function that can truncate the long strings and return it in whatever format you like and use that function in the f-string

```
>>> def trunc(s, left=14, right=6, seperator='...'):
...     return s[:left]+seperator+s[-right:]
... 
>>> 
>>> for key in lines:
...     print(f'{trunc(key)}')
... 
ThisIsMyFilexy...890.py
ThisIsMyFilexy...90.pdf
ThisIsMyFilexy...90.gif
ThisIsMyFilexy...90.jpg
```